# C hashing function taking 2 numbers

Tags: c, hash

I need an non cryptograhic hashing function which takes 2 32 bit unsigned integers and returns just one. Is there such a hashing algorithm? And how would i create one?

Comment: No, such a function does not exist. You must create it yourself. (which is very easy)

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function based on djb2a:

```
uint32_t hash(uint32_t n, uint32_t n2) {
    uint32_t hash = 5381;
    {
        int c;
        
        while ((c = n>>=2))
                hash = hash * 33 ^ c;
        while ((c = n2<<=2))
                hash = hash * 33 ^ c;
    }
    
    return hash;
}
```